# How do I get my if statement to search for delimiters?

Tags: java

iv'e been searching around but it's hard to find an answer for this specific code. I'm looking to make my if statement search for the delimiter - then use the apply the integers before and after to a variable. E.G. if they inputted 1-50 it would apply 1 to int a and 50 to int b. Here's the if statement i'm looking to apply it to. It would come from the input variable :

```
   if (yes.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
       if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && input.equalsIgnoreCase("instant")){
           Thread.sleep(1);
       }
       else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && input.equalsIgnoreCase("generate")){
           Thread.sleep(randomInt);
       }
       else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("generate") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("instant")){
       int x =Integer.parseInt(input);
       x = x*60000;
       Thread.sleep(x);
       }
       else if (a.equals("quit" )){
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else if (a.equals("Quit")){
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else if (a.equals("")){

       }
       else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please check the answer then try again ");
              i = i-2;
           }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StringTokenizer class to parse strings. For ex:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("1-50","-");
int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
int b = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
```

If you do this; a will be 1, b will be 50. I didn't try this code but it must be like this.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). It will return you a `String[]`, which you will later can parse using [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

for example:

```
String s = "1-50";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("-")));
```

wil print [1,50]